# Using S3FS in a docker container ran by the mesos containerizer

Tags: docker, mesos, fuse, s3fs, apache-aurora

I have a docker image where i use S3FS to mount an S3 bucket to use as a regular filesystem. Now, this works without any issues when i run the docker container using the docker engine and setting privileged mode, but seems to fail when trying to run this container using the mesos containerizer.

I'm trying to run this container via the Aurora scheduler and the error i'm getting is the following:

fuse: device not found, try 'modprobe fuse' first

I've tried mounting nfs shares from a container running under mesos before, so this seems a bit strange to me, does anyone have any information on this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable fuse support on the kernel side (installing and loading fuse kernel module, so that `/dev/fuse` device will be available). The fact that you were able to use nfs doesn't matter, as nfs support is implemented directly in kernel and not via fuse in userspace.

Comment: is loading a kernel module within a docker container something that's supported ?

Comment: I don't think so. You need to understand that while you can bundle all libraries inside the container as you like, you will still depend on a kernel of host machine on which the container is running. Any kernel tweaks needs to be done directly on a container host machine. I suggest to check how mesos handles that.

Comment: i recently created an issue on the mesos jira regarding this issue, as it sounds like it's probably on the mesos containerizer side, since using the docker engine seems to work fine: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MESOS-7685

Comment: in case it helpe anyone, the workaround i used in the mean time was to mount the s3 bucket on the host OS, then have mesos mount THAT folder onto the docker container when it runs. In my case, using Aurora as a mesos framework, i did this via the aurora -global_container_mounts parameter